# How merge 7 files into 1 file using awk each of the files contains first column as currency [common] and second column as their count

Tags: awk

I have 7 files example as per below- I have just given 3 entries as sample from just 2 files. There could be multiple entries. All 7 files have same currencies.

```
file1
22 HKD
5  JPY
3  AUD

file 2
23  HKD
5   JPY
2   AUD
```

and so on.. file3, file4, file5, file6,file 7

I want to see only one file whose output is like below-
merged file--

```
currency,Count_1, Count_2,Count_3,Count_4,Count_5,Count_6,Count_7
HKD,22,23,22,23,21,22,23
JPY,5,5,4,5,6,5,5
AUD,3,2,3,3,3,3,2
```

Columns count_1, count_2,...count_7 represents 2nd columns each for every currency for all 7 files [Output should comma separated]. I am new to unix/awk and really need your help in arranging the data. I am not able to paste the data in tabular [columns] format. Please bear with me. Sorry. I apologise as I have changed few things here.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap your code in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As OP told to make it comma separated by comma so adding that solution now.

```
paste FILe[1-7] |
awk 'BEGIN{
  print "currency,Count_1,Count_2,Count_3,Count_4,Count_5,Count_6,Count_7"}
{
  printf "%s,%s,",$2,$1;
  for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=2){
    printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}
}' OFS=,
```

---

Following `awk` and `paste` combination may help you here.

```
paste Input_file[1-7] |
awk 'BEGIN{
  print "currency  Count_1 Count_2 Count_3 Count_4 Count_5 Count_6 Count_7"
}
{
  printf "%s ",$1;
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){
    printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}
}' |
column -t
```

Comment: Many thanks @RavinderSingh13! I have made an error in my above requirement. My input files are in the below format and not in the format as I have specified.file1
22 HKD
5  JPY
3  AUD while file2,3,4,5,6,7 are same as file1 format. The output should be as , "comma seperated. eg The output file should read as currency,count_1,count_2,count_3,......so on same for the values of counts for each currencies.

Comment: @Shlshgaikwad, kindly update your post with correct details and let me know as from this comment it is not clear.

Comment: Appreciate your help @RavinderSingh13! I have update the original requirement above.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13... One more thing I have corrected is input file. Currency is second column while count is first column in all input files. The above code considers Currency as first column and count as second column. Either I will have to change the column in all input files or need above code changed.Kindly advise on how to go about this.

Comment: I have pasted the changed input files requirement in the original message. Pasting the same here again input files are as per here--file1
22 HKD
5  JPY
3  AUD

file 2
23  HKD
5   JPY
2   AUD

Comment: @Shlshgaikwad, please let me know reason of removing the correct answer to this one??

Comment: I am thankful to you.. I dont know how the answer got removed and who removed it...By the way I used | awk '{print($2 "\t" $1)}' to exchange my column in the input files and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch errors like non-matching columns you might also find the `join` command useful:

```
files=(file*)
joined=$(<${files[0]})
for f in ${files[@]:1};do joined=$(join <(echo "$joined") $f);done
echo "$joined"
```